# mysql statement works on my desktop but fails on my web host

Tags: mysql, sql

I use XAMPP on my desktop (Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1  MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $)

I have a MYSQL SELECT statement that works fine in my desktop application, even ran it in phpMyadmin and works correctly.

When I move my application up to my web host the statement fails.  My web host runs Apache with MySQL client version: 5.0.92
When I used phpMyadmin on my web host it gives me the error:

```
FUNCTION nwilin5_eib_jtest.FIELD does not exist
```

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT a.*, p.name as parent, p.id as parentid, c.name as cat
    , c.id as catid,u.username as user, f.itemid as featured
    , f.payment_date as FeaturedPayDate, f.limit_date as FeaturedExpDate  
FROM jos_classifiedsredux_ads as a  
LEFT JOIN jos_users as u 
    ON a.userid = u.id  
LEFT JOIN jos_classifiedsredux_pay4featuredad as f 
    ON a.id = f.itemid  
INNER JOIN jos_classifiedsredux_categories as c 
    ON a.category = c.id  
LEFT JOIN jos_classifiedsredux_categories as p 
    ON c.parent = p.id  
WHERE a.published = 1 
ORDER BY FIELD (a.id, 137, 226, 134, 135, 220, 240, 233, 219, 146, 138, 136, 133)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `FIELD` and `(` in your `ORDER BY`...

Change:

`ORDER BY FIELD (a.id, 137, 226, 134, 135, 220...`

To:

`ORDER BY FIELD(a.id, 137, 226, 134, 135, 220...`

Why does this matter?

Your test server and your production server likely have a different setting for the [`IGNORE_SPACE` mode... which permits a space between the function call (`FIELD`), and the parameter list when enabled.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space)

> Permit spaces between a function name and the “(” character. This
>   causes built-in function names to be treated as reserved words. As a
>   result, identifiers that are the same as function names must be quoted
>   as described in Section 8.2, “Schema Object Names”. For example,
>   because there is a COUNT() function, the use of count as a table name
>   in the following statement causes an error:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE count (i INT); 
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax 
> The table name should be quoted:
>
> mysql> CREATE TABLE `count` (i INT); 
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> The IGNORE_SPACE SQL mode applies to built-in functions, not to
>   user-defined functions or stored functions. It is always permissible
>   to have spaces after a UDF or stored function name, regardless of
>   whether IGNORE_SPACE is enabled.

Comment: WOW! works, wasn't aware of the IGNORE_SPACE mode (i am sure most people don't)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix - change the ORDER BY to just ORDER BY a.id, ..., and it should work.

Comment: This would change the results of his `ORDER BY`... the OP is using `FIELD` to hard-code the order of `a.id`.

Comment: NAW that fails to use the ordered list I create, merely sorts on the key (a.id)